# Is working for a data selling company, that sells data that can potentially assist haram allowed

Tags: halal-haram, software

Thanks for reading this . I have a question for someone who has more Islamic knowledge. The question is that is it permissible to work for a company which sells data that can potentially be used for haram stuff like betting. The company doesn't provide any betting services it just sells data to anyone who would like to buy it.
Please take a look at here http://www.coredata.eu/ and let me know if it's ok to work for them. The data maybe sold to betting sites that's my concern. please enlighten me thanks

Answer (score -1):

It is impermissible to work for a data selling company, that sells data that can potentially assist in haram because it impermissible to assist/help each other in sin as Allah says:

> “And cooperate in righteousness and piety, but **do not cooperate in sin and aggression**. And fear Allah; indeed, Allah is severe in penalty”
>
> [al-Maa’idah 5:2](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://quran.com/5/2&ved=2ahUKEwiQzICKpoj8AhUe7rsIHR63Bg8QFnoECAwQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1gqrpi_OVHi2ijIcEeQ3OZ)

For similar fatwas see :

**[1](https://islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/258914), [2](https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/137166), [3](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.islamweb.net/amp/en/fatwa/361468/)**

Answer (score -1):

You are working for a company that is creating/getting data from multiple sources. What that company do with it, is not your concern. You are not directly included in that company's business. Its their choice.
It's like working for a bank.